# Remove spaces from javascript string but not all spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string

```
str = 'first last1; first last2; first Last3;';
```

I am looking to remove the spaces only after the semicolons.

I have tried using

```
str = str.replace(';' + /\s+/g, ';');
```

and

```
str = str.replace((';' + /\s+/g), ';');
```

but it is not working.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about `str.replace(/;\s+/g, ';');` ? Concatenating a string with a regular expression won't produce the result you might expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
str = 'first last1; first last2; first Last3;';
str = str.replace(/;\s+/g, ';');
alert( str );
```

You were quite close:

```
str = str.replace(/;\s+/g, ';');
```

Comment: it is better: str = str.replace(/;\s+/g, ';');